# How do I pin one image to the background-image (responsive)?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I need your help! I have a background image and I need one part of that image to move (rotate or zoom) whenever you hover it. [This image is just an example but it's pretty similar what i have, except mine is more centered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKkVt.jpg)

I want the little sticker on the bowl to move a little (rotate like 20 degrees or any sort of animation to be honest) whenever you mouse over it.

I've already cropped the sticker so now I have two images. I'm using the background as my div's bg. Here's my code:

```
HTML:
<header class="background-image">
    <div class="sticker"></div>
</header>

CSS:
.background-image {
background-image: url(../img/bg-principal.png) !important;
background: white;
height: 90%;
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

I've managed to place the sticker where it's supposed to be, but it's not responsive. When the screen is resized, the little sticker moves and I can't seem to find a solution for that. Basically what I need is to pin the sticker to the background image, but I have no idea if that's possible. I looked around and couldn't find anything that worked.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there any way that I can do this using only CSS? I only have basic knowledge of jQuery so I'd like to avoid that but if it's the only solution I'd be fine with that too.

Thanks!!

EDIT: I tried using a transparent png sticker the same size as the background, but since I need the hover effect, I end up having the same problem.

Comment: What if your transparent png sticker is actually the same size of the background? Than you'll have no problems, 2 elements, two background contains one of which zooms on hover.  ... otherwise, having a small png sticker - you'll run into calculation problems trying to have it always in the same desired position and resize like the parent contained bg image...

Comment: Hmmmm... even with two same/sized images the problem is still there in the responsiveness and centering the actual `transform-origin` for the animation rotation etc....

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I actually tried that and it worked perfectly, but then I ran into the same problem: since I need to apply the hover effect on the sticker,  if the image takes up the entire screen it doesn't work. I would need to create a new element that I could mouse over and place it on top of the sticker... so basically the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vw as a unit of measurement, the sticker can track based on the size of the element

```css
.background-image {
background-image:
 url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/butterfly_flower_01_hd_pictures_166973.jpg) !important;

height: 40vw;
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.sticker{
 width:20px; height:20px; position:absolute;
 top: 20vw; left:40vw;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<header class="background-image">
    <div class="sticker"></div>
 
</header>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If I understand correctly the op was having trouble maintaining the correct position of the sticker relative to the background, to see this you'd need to hit the `Expand snippet` option and resize the browser window, though I may have misinterpreted the question

Comment: andrew... the background image has the property `contain` ... and your sticker? The proportions / positions will be messed up.... if you realize how `contain` works. Also your sticker has always the same size. Your code formatting is also strange.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution!
This is my final code:

```
HTML:
<div class="background">
 <img src="..."/>
 <div id="pin" class="sticker">
 </div>
</div>

CSS:
.background {
  margin:10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.map img {
  max-width:100%;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  background-image:   url(...);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

#pin {
  top:60%;
  left:46%;
}
```